# PHP: preg_replace eats all memory

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, out-of-memory

I am processing couple of GB of text, and my script dies on preg_replace(). After some research I extract the problematic part of the text, where the leak appears.

```
preg_replace('/\b\p{L}{0,2}\b/u', '', "\x65\xe2\xba\xb7\x69\xe3\xb1\xae");
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 251105872 bytes)

I am trying to delete short (up to 2 chars) words. Also I found out, if I change regexp to:

```
preg_replace('/\b\p{L}{1,2}\b/u', '', "\x65\xe2\xba\xb7\x69\xe3\xb1\xae");
```

it works just OK.

Somebody can explain whats going on please? 1st example works on 99% texts.

Comment: Are you passing the entire "couple gigs of text" to the function at once?  Meaning you've first read the entire file into memory?

Comment: Nope. I got text files, each is around 100 kb

Comment: Why would you want to replace zero letters with nothing?  This looks to me like a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" kind of question. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b\p{L}{0,2}\b
        ^
```

This 0 here will make the regex match in more places than you need and you get possibly twice or more to match and replace.

E.g: You get 344 matches with a "Lorem ipsum" text with `\b\p{L}{0,2}\b` ([regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tJ7kK7)) but only 19 with `\b\p{L}{1,2}\b` ([regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hW9zE4)).

And if it's a replace, you get so many more to do!

Comment: sure, I understand that. But what I don't understand, how it is possible PHP doesn't have enough memory on 8 characters long string. 'PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 251105872 bytes)'

Comment: @2ge Well, I guess it's because `\p{L}` contains lots and lots of characters and it's checking for each character 1 more time at each matching position, which turns into millions of more 'checks'.